# Solve a Stack State Diagram

Tags: code-golf, code-generation, stack

A stack state diagram shows how the values on one stack are changed into the other. For example, this is a stack state diagram:

```
3 0 2 1 0
```

This means that there is a stack initially containing 3 values (the `3` part). These values are indexed from 0 to 2, with 0 at the top: `2 1 0`. The next part `0 2 1 0` describes the final state of the stack: the value that was originally on top of the stack has been copied to the back as well.

These transformations happen on a stack that has support for several data types:

- The "value" type, which is what is originally on the stack. This could be a string, integer, etc. but its value does not need to be known.
- The "list" type, which is a list containing values of any data type.

To model this transformation, the following operations are permitted:

- `S`: Swap the two values on top of the stack: `2 1 0` → `2 0 1`
- `D`: Duplicate the value on top of the stack: `1 0` → `1 0 0`
- `R`: Remove the top value on the stack. `2 1 0` → `2 1`
- `L`: Turn the top value into a one-element list containing that value: `2 1 0` → `2 1 (0)`
- `C`: Concatenate the top two lists on the stack: `2 (1) (0)` → `2 (1 0)`
- `U`: Place all the values from a list onto the stack: `2 (1 0)` → `2 1 0`

These are equivalent to the [Underload](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload) commands `~ : ! a * ^`, provided that no other commands are used.

`S`, `D`, `R`, and `L` can be used with any values on top of the stack, but `C` and `U` must have lists on top of the stack to function. A submission whose generated sequences attempt to preform invalid operations (like `D` on an empty stack or `U` on a non-list) is *wrong* and must be <s>punished</s> fixed.

To solve a stack state diagram, find a sequence of commands that will correctly transform the initial stack state into the new one. For example, one solution to `3: 0 2 1 0` is `LSLCSLCULSLCLSLDCSC USLCU`:

```
   2 1 0
L  2 1 (0)
S  2 (0) 1
L  2 (0) (1)
C  2 (0 1)
S  (0 1) 2
L  (0 1) (2)
C  (0 1 2)
U  0 1 2
L  0 1 (2)
S  0 (2) 1
L  0 (2) (1)
C  0 (2 1)
L  0 ((2 1))
S  ((2 1)) 0
L  ((2 1)) (0)
D  ((2 1)) (0) (0)
C  ((2 1)) (0 0)
S  (0 0) ((2 1))
C  (0 0 (2 1))
U  0 0 (2 1)
S  0 (2 1) 0
L  0 (2 1) (0)
C  0 (2 1 0)
U  0 2 1 0
```

Your task is to write a program that takes a stack state diagram and outputs a solution.

## Test Cases

```
2 1 0       ->

3 2 0       -> SR

9           -> RRRRRRRRR

2 0 1 0     -> LSLCDCUR

2 0 1 1     -> SD

6 2         -> RRSRSRSR

5 0 1 2 3 4 -> LSLCSLCSLCSLCU

4 2 0 1 3 2 -> LSLCSLSCSLCULSLSCSLSCLSLDCSCUSLCU
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid answer (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Can you have a list containing lists? EDIT: Nevermind, you can, it's in the example.

Comment: Does the `C` need lists on top and second position of stack? or the element in second position could be added to a list on top?

Comment: `C` needs lists on both positions. It doesn't make sense to concatenate a value and a list.

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3, 84 bytes

```py
lambda n,*s:"DLL"+"L".join(i*"SLSC"+"LSLSCDURLCULCULSC"for i in s[::-1])+n*"SR"+"UR"
```

Usage:

```
# Example: 4 2 0 1 3 2 -> LSLCSLSCSLCULSLSCSLSCLSLDCSCUSLCU
>>> f = lambda ...
>>> f(4, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2)
'DLLSLSCSLSCLSLSCDURLCULCULSCLSLSCSLSCSLSCLSLSCDURLCULCULSCLSLSCLSLSCDURLCULCULSCLLSLSCDURLCULCULSCLSLSCSLSCLSLSCDURLCULCULSCSRSRSRSRUR'
```

**Explanation:** To start off we duplicate the zero and wrap it in a list:

```
DL -> 3 2 1 0 (0)
```

This is our base. Now I will explain a general algorithm that turns `... 1 0 (x)` into `... 1 0 (i x)` for arbitrary integer `i`. I will use as an example `i = 2`, and we have some arbitrary list `(x)`. We start by wrapping our current list `(x)` into another list:

```
L -> 3 2 1 0 ((x))
```

Now we repeat the following sequence `i` times:

```
SLSC -> 3 2 1 (0 (x))
SLSC -> 3 2 (1 0 (x))
```

Now we're ready to insert the 2 into list `(x)`. This goes as follows:

```
LSLSC -> 3 (2 (1 0 (x)))
DU -> 3 (2 (1 0 (x))) 2 (1 0 (x))
RLCU -> 3 2 (1 0 (x)) 2
LCU -> 3 2 1 0 (x) 2
LSC -> 3 2 1 0 (2 x)
```

Note that we keep pushing new integers on the left. So the very first `(0)` we started with stays on the right.

After we have inserted every integer we need into the list we remove the rest of the stack by swapping and removing *n* time (`SR`). Finally we unpack our list and delete the first `0` we inserted to start our list (`UR`).

Comment: Did you mean to type `s` instead of `l`?

Comment: @ZacharyT Oops, yep. It worked while shuffling things around because `l` was defined on my REPL.

Comment: The example shown doesn't seem to work... (`DLLSLSCSLSCSLSCSLSCLSLSCDURLCULCULSCLSLSCSLSCSLSCLSLSCDURLCULCULSCLSLSCSLSCLSLSCDURLCULCULSCLSLSCLSLSCDURLCULCULSCLLSLSCDURLCULCULSCSRSRSRSRUR `). It tries to execute an `S` instruction when there's only 1 value on the stack.

Comment: @Challenger5 And I also forgot to update the example... Should be fixed now.

Comment: Yep, looks good now!

Comment: @Challenger5 Did you expect such a... static solution, as opposed to a more dynamic solver?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Challenger5 Did you expect a solution like this, where a string just gets repeated a number of times, or a more dynamic solver program?

Comment: Anything is fine. I like it!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the test case `6 2`.

Comment: @Challenger5 It works fine for me. Output is `DLLSLSCSLSCLSLSCDURLCULCULSCSRSRSRSRSRSRUR` which evaluates to `2` when the stack is initially `5 4 3 2 1 0`

Comment: @orlp: I tried it again, and it seems to work, but unless I made a mistake somewhere it evaluates to `(2)` instead of `2`.

Comment: @Challenger5 You made a mistake somewhere, I verified by hand.

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 54 bytes

Just a translation from orlp's Python solution into CJam. There's nothing new here.

```
"DLL"q~("SR"*\W%{"SLSC"*"LSLSCDURLCULCULSC"+}%'L*\"UR"
```

Explanation:

```
"DLL"                  e# Push string
q~                     e# Read input and evaluate
(                      e# Pop the first value
"SR"                   e# Push string
*                      e# Repeat string n times
\                      e# Swap (bring s to front)
W%                     e# Reverse
{                      e# For each:
  "SLSC"               e#   Push string
  *                    e#   Repeat i times
  "LSLSCDURLCULCULSC"+ e#   Append string to end
}%                     e# End
'L*                    e# Join with 'L'
\                      e# Swap (bring "SR"*n to front)
"UR"                   e# Push string
                       e# [Stack is implicitly output.]
```